# plot lines using ggplot and fit a linear regression line

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, dplyr, time-series

I have generated a toy data as following:

```
toy.df <- data.frame(ID = rep(paste("S",1:25, sep = "_") ,4) , x  = rep(seq(1,5), 20), y = rnorm(100), color_code = rnorm(100)
                 ,group = rep(letters[1:4] , 25) )
```

I would like to use ggplot to generate multiple lines as well as points in 4 facets and fit a linear regression line to each the group of lines in each facet.

```
toy.df %>% ggplot(aes(x = x, y = y, group = ID)) +
 facet_wrap( . ~ group, scales = 'free', ncol = 2)+
 geom_point() + 
 geom_line(aes(color = color_code)) +
 geom_smooth(method = 'lm')
```

But it does not generate the lines over the x axis (1 to 5)

Do you have any idea how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You are using ID as `group` and each group contains only one observation. So, it is not possible to fit linear regression using only one observation. Removing `group = ID` works fine like

```
library(tidyverse)

toy.df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  facet_wrap( . ~ group, scales = 'free', ncol = 2)+
  geom_point() + 
  geom_smooth(method=lm, se=F, formula = y ~ x)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply I would like to have 5 lines and the fitted regression in the plot. Maybe I have not generated the to plot correctly. maybe sample Id should be rep(paste("S",1:25, sep = "_") ,4). Do you know how can I post this/

Comment: Your toy data is not sufficient. Do you want to plot y vs color_code? Can you show your expected output may be uisng hand drawn image.

Comment: I would like to plot y vs x for each IDand color each line based on continuous value that is generated in color_code column.

Comment: `color` argument within `geom_line` should be a character or factor not continuous value.

Comment: I see. how would you plot the 5 lines in each facet without coloring/